# Time complexity in search of a list within a tree

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I am working on a project on algorithms and data structures classes.

If I have a binary search tree, where each node contains:

```
  typedef struct Node {
  char* name;
  List* list;
  struct Node *right;
  struct Node *left;
} Node;
```

and I want to search a determined value inside that list, what would be the time complexity of this search? I understand that the time complexity of a search in a list is O(n) but I want to also account for the time complexity of the search in the tree. The list is not sorted and BST is ordered alphabetically.

Comment: the list is not sorted and BST is ordered alphabetically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *non-balanced* binary search tree can degenerate to a linked list, so the worst-case complexity is still `O(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

The answers boils down to "Is the tree sorted" (And in useful order..)

If you need to search all nodes, and all lists in each node, the (average case) time complexity will be `O(n*m)`, where `n` is the average length of a list, and `m` is the number of nodes in the tree.

If you can check only a certain path (similar to how you can search only one path in binary search tree), the (average case) complexity is `O(n*logm)`.